# Where is CSS file of the Paypal (Braintree) in Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento, payment

I want to make few changes in the UI of the Payment method page in Checkout of Magento. But I am unable to find the path of the file for Paypal (Braintree) payment form in Magento.

[image: 1]

Not able to find the path of particular CSS file to change the UI

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific CSS to apply for Paypal Braintree. But if there are any third party form (inside iframe) then magento will not allow to add CSS on this. Otherwise you can apply any css for checkout page using the custom css inside your active theme.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Vendor_CustomCss::css/css-module.css"/>
</head>
```